# how to send formatted text in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am developing one application that has many controls to format the text.
The controls are like colors,Font Style,Border,Giving Background to Text,and even animations.
My Question is can I send this formatted text through SMS and MMS to my friends?is apple support this?
please give me any link or any reference where i can study this and implement it in my project.
thanx in Advance....

Comment: not formatted sms but formatted text that i want to send using sms in iphone is this possible?

Comment: no its not, you can however render an image of it and send that. like the 5 billion apps in the appstore do already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know its not possible, I have seen SO many of these apps on the store that basically just save as a picture and send as a picture.

As of now... in the SDK `MFMessageComposeViewController` doesn't support MMS.

Although you can render an image and send it.

HOW DO THEY DO IT????

They might send a request back to their server which sends an mms from there?

Here are some options:

This is not possible with the current MessageUI API: the MSMessageComposeViewController doesn't accept attachments like the MFMailComposeViewController does.

The only way to do this currently is to use an external service that allows you to send mms via a REST call for example.

GSMA defines a REST specification for exactly this purpose: http://www.gsmworld.com/oneapi/reference_documentation-version_1.html (multiple pdf's on this page)

Try to find a local service provider that implements this specification and you're good to go.

Just to add the direct wiki link to the OneAPI MMS spec: http://gsma.securespsite.com/access/Access%20API%20Wiki/MMS%20RESTful%20API.aspx and a link to the PHP/Java sandbox https://github.com/OneAPI/GSMA-OneAPI where MMS can be tested locally . Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Apple only supports sending of [`SMS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) text messages, use the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Since sms only supports sending plain text you can't set any format.

`MFMessageComposeViewController` does not support [`MMS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_Messaging_Service), which would allow you to send formated messages.